# Matlab plotting through origin regardless of only negative or only positive data

Tags: matlab, variables, plot, automation

this one should be really easy to answer, yet I am surprised it is nowhere described:

I have variable data, and often when I simply plot, I get a close-up on the y-axis (x-axis is time and starts always with a zero). So I get y-values from 16-17, but the zero is nowhere to be seen. I know you can give matlab an YLim value, yet sometimes because my data is variable, I get a range from -50-100 in y. If i had specified before that YLim is [0 20] I wouldnt see it at all, which is not what I want. I just always want to have the origin plotted with my data, how do I do that (without a rigid interval like [-1000 1000], since sometimes I have y values from -0,01-0,001 and wouldnt see it)? Please help if you have an idea!

Thanks!

UPDATE 1: perfectly solved!

Follow-up question:

There is one thing I didnt mention: I need to do this for all my 18 subplots. How can I avoid hardcoding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is automatically is to use:

`ylim([min([y 0]) max([y,0])])`

this way, it will start or stop at `0` if `0` is not already in the range of `y`

or better, if you want to keep the rounded values matlab provides (eg plot on [0,6] and not on [0,5.872]), first plot your data with `plot(x,y)`, then change the ylim values to 0 if needed:

`ylim([min([ylim 0]) max([ylim 0])])`

Comment: You're welcome. To be fair I'm pretty sure Luis Mendo's second solution works too, because it is like adding an invisible point for an unknown `x` with an `y` of `0` thereby forcing matlab to include `y=0` in the plot (no matter if you add `NaN` and `0` before or after your vectors `x` and `y` and no matter if your `y` is only positive, only negative, or positive and negative).

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to manually modify axis size:

```
x = 1:10; %/ example x
y = 5 + rand(1,10); %// example y. Values between 5 and 6
plot(x,y) %// do the plot normally
ax = axis; %// get axis size
ax(3) = min(ax(3),0); %// if the y-axis lower limit is positive, make it 0
axis(ax) %// apply new axis size values
```

---

This also seems to work: just use

```
plot([x NaN],[y 0])
```

That is, include a point with `x` value set to `NaN` and `y` value set to `0`. The point doesn't get plotted (because of the `NaN` value) but it forces the `y` axis to strech out to `0`.

Comment: the interesting thing is what happens when the random data is negative, and the next time positive. eithre Ylim is [0 positive] or [negative 0] but i wouldnt know where to put the zero every time. besides, the data comes automatically, i cant just always change the zeros position.

Comment: I don't get it. In the first approach, just paste my last two lines after your code. Doesn't that work? Also, doesn't the second approach work with your values?

Comment: I thank you for your approach but I think I will stick to yoh.lej's because it targets exactly what I needed, and I think you might have misunderstood me somewhere. I wanted to have 0 in my plots thats all, there are no nans.

Comment: And I think you misunderstood my code. Did you even try it? `NaN`s are not plotted (by definition) :-)